# Why am I getting “undefined reference to sqrt” error even though I include math.h header? is there a permanent solution other than adding -lm?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2;
float distance;
//take the 1st points coordinates x axis and y axis
printf("Enter the coordinates of 1st point: ");
scanf("%d %d", &x1, &y1);

//take the 2st points coordinates x axis and y axis
printf("Enter the coordinates of 2nd point: ");
scanf("%d %d", &x2, &y2);

x = x2 - x1;
y = y2 - y1;

distance = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));

//display result
printf("Distance = %.2f", distance);

return 0;
```

}

when i compile the program an error message is shown in the terminal window.

**/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8GnBrR.o: in function 'main':
distance2.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to 'sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

is there a permanent solution for this problem other than "gcc filename.c -o filename -lm"

Comment: To quote https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html - "Link with -lm." That's the official way to use that function.

Comment: Yes there are other permanent "solutions". They're not even *worth discussing* because of how complicated they're c.f. 4 more keystrokes on the linking command line. The proper solution is to accept that you need to link with `-lm`, period.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between *declarations* and *definitions*. A *declaration* is telling the compiler that something exists *somewhere*, but not right here. A *definition* is the actual implementation of the something. In the case of `sqrt` the standard `<math.h>` header *declares* the function, but the *definition* is in the `m` library, which you need to link with using the `-l` option.

Comment: *is there a permanent solution for this problem other than "gcc filename.c -o filename -lm"*  You're going to have a real fun time writing code to connect to a database that uses SSL to secure its connections if you don't want to link in libraries...

Comment: If adding 4 more characters to a command line is an issue, developing applications might not be the ideal task.

Comment: `$ echo '#!/bin/sh' >compile.sh` -- `$ echo 'gcc "$@" -lm' >>compile.sh` -- `$ chmod a+x compile.sh` -- `$ ./compile.sh -Wall -Wextra foo.c`

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` is defined in `libm` (the maths library). Unless you link with `-lm` you will get an undefined symbol. Alternatives would include defining your own `sqrt` function (don't do that).

Answer (score 0):

Now, #include<Math.h> library does not come with Linux terminal call. This library only in C library so, it is unable to fetch the library using GCC compiler. So, we have to put flag(-)lm that is '-lm'.
Example:
your program is test.c
you have to compile in terminal:
=>  gcc -o texecute test.c -lm
this '-lm' token helps you to compile the program successfully.

Comment: This is not true. The correct answer has been given in comments: `math.h` contains only the declaration, telling the compiler not to worry about those undefined `sqrt` symbol, and promising that they will be defined somewhere else. Linking (not compiling, even tho both are done with `gcc` command) with `-lm` fulfill this earlier promise, by adding the compiled code (`libm.so`) that contains the actual implementation of `sqrt`. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring some new information that wasn't already given years ago.